# does Session.Clear(); clears all sessions data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I Want to clear one session Data but it's clearing both Sessions data. below is my 2 MVC action methods which are used to clear Session data.

1)

```
public int Clearsesson()
        {
            int i = 0;
            List<Wish_Product> products = new List<Wish_Product>();
            if (**Session["WishItem"]** != null)
            {              
                Session.Clear();
                i = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                i = 0;
            }
            return i;

        }
```

2)

```
 public int Clearsesson2()
        {
            int i = 0;
            List<Cart_Product> products = new List<Cart_Product>();
            if (**Session["CartItem"]** != null)
            {
               // Session.Remove("CartItem");
                Session.Clear();
                i = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                i = 0;
            }
            return i;

        }
```

So like this I am storing Data in two Sessions but when I run this asp.net MVC Action method to clear One session data, it automatically clears second one Session Data too.

Why so like this? Please make it clear to me why it's happening.

Or what I've to do to solve this problem?

Comment: 1) Session["WishItem"]                                                                                  2) Session["CartItem"]    these are two Sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**, on the current collection.

According to ASP.NET documentation, [`HttpSessionState.Clear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) method removes *all keys and values* from currently active session state collection (it doesn't destroy user's session state base), so that both `Session["WishItem"]` & `Session["CartItem"]` values are cleared together from collection when the method is executed, **but the session state base kept alive**.

There are 2 different session collection keys in this case & actually both of them using *same session state*. To clear single session data, there are 2 different ways:

1) Remove session key using [`Session.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.remove(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Session.Remove("WishItem");
```

2) Assign `null` value to the session state based with its key.

```
Session["WishItem"] = null;
```

The difference between them is that the former deletes both keys and values so that it won't appear as key-value pair in session collection anymore, and the latter overwrites current collection value with specified key but the key name still unchanged.

Therefore, you can remove each session data separately without clearing another session key like this:

```
public int ClearSession()
{
    int i = 0;
    // other code logic
    if (Session["WishItem"] != null)
    {              
        // only WishItem key has cleared
        Session.Remove("WishItem");
        i = 1;
    }

    // other code logic
}

public int ClearSession2()
{
    int i = 0;
    // other code logic
    if (Session["CartItem"] != null)
    {              
        // only CartItem key has cleared
        Session.Remove("CartItem");
        i = 1;
    }

    // other code logic
}
```

Note that each authenticated user always be assigned with one session state base, hence using `Session.Clear` removes all existing key-value pairs stored in session collection for current user (doesn't affect other user's session state).

Comment: First of all thank you for answering in very detail :)                                     
 Now I am using    "Session["WishItem"] = null"    method to make it null but when I run my project then in the View I am getting this error/Exception:- "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in this Part of Code in View =>                                                "@if (Session.Count > 0 && Session["WishItem"].ToString() != null)"

Comment: You can solve it with null coalescing before `ToString`: `@if (Session.Count > 0 && (Session["WishItem"] ?? String.Empty).ToString())` or simply null-check: `@if (Session.Count > 0 && Session["WishItem"] != null)`.

Comment: Yes, It works now ... Thank very much again for solving my Problem. :)